# warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, gdb, debugging

I'm using Qt Creator on Ubuntu to develop C.  Whenever I run with the debugger, I get the message `warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Invalid argument`.  This happens even with a `hello world` program. How can I solve this?

Comment: Hey Joel, did you find the solution for this issue? The copying of libQtCore.so.4 doesnt work for me

Comment: No... I just ignore the warning since debugging is working fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug in Qt Creator, which is not invoking GDB correctly (either inside a pseudoterminal, or with command line arguments that tell it not to expect to be run inside a pseudoterminal).  It is also a bug in GDB, which could figure out for itself that it wasn't being run inside a pseudoterminal and behave accordingly.   I suspect the GDB maintainers will take the position that this is Qt Creator's fault, and vice versa, alas.

There is a claimed workaround here: http://www.qtforum.org/article/31905/debugging-qt-application-on-linux.html but it sounds kinda dodgy to me.

Comment: What are the consequences of this bug, besides the warning message?  Any chance of checking if it's fixed in source control (in either project) so I could build it?

Comment: I dunno!  My diagnosis is *entirely* based on what you wrote + what I found typing "qt creator gdb controlling terminal" into Google.  Some people seem to think it makes the debugger not work, but if the debugger works for you, I think it should be harmless.

Comment: Well, I'm just starting with Qt Creator, but in my little test program with a simple *for* loop, the debugger seemed to work

Comment: It is of no consequence. We get this all the time and debugging works without a hitch. It's just a minor annoyance, which might explain why it remains unfixed since version 1.3.

Comment: Hmmm, can I fix it and submit a patch?

Answer (score 0):

Whether this warning is a bug or not, it is informative as a clue that you have the option to tell QtCreator to cause your program to run in a terminal which may be useful for debug output. See [Setup GDB with QtCreator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305097/setup-gdb-with-qtcreator) to enable this option.

If you don't want a terminal open, then just ignore the warning.