# Setup GDB with QtCreator

Tags: c++, opencv, gdb, cmake, qt-creator

I have a simple project using OpenCV and cmake, and has two source files only segmentation.h and segmentation.cpp.

Here is the cmakefile:

```
project(Segment)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE true)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    message(STATUS "GCC detected, adding compile flags")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O0 -g -std=c++98 -Wall")
endif(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
add_executable(Lulu segmentation.cpp segmentation.h)
target_link_libraries(Lulu ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I created a Debug build with argument sent to cmake: -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug . However QtCreator still skip the break points, and can't start gdb properly:

```
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device\n"
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but that *gdb* warning probably has nothing to do with it not working, it just means gdb is not running in a real terminal. Can you find the actual compile commands used, and check that `-g` switch is really given there? Also curious, why ancient `-std=c++98`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to **Project**, **Run** and in the run settings check the box that say **Run in Terminal**. It will make QT Creator launch the program inside a XTerm (default) that plays well with gdb and makes the **&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for device\n"** problem go away.

By default, when launching the debugger, it will also bring QT Creator to the foreground and thus hide the terminal that was brought up. To stop this behaviour go to: **Tools**, **Options**, **Debugger**. In the **General** tab, untick the check box that say **Bring Qt Creator to foreground when application interrupts**.

If you want to change the terminal, you can do so in **Options**, **Environment**. In the **System** section the **Terminal** to what you want. For native Ubuntu / Gnome terminal, set it to **/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x**. The parameters in this setting must tell the terminal to execute an external command or program.