# GDB Debugger in QtCreator

Tags: gdb, qt-creator

I'm having problems debugging my C++ code. I'm using GDB with QtCreator and when the code stops at a breakpoint and I step over (either using keyboard shortcut, or from the menu) most of the times it goes to an irrelevant file (like memory or algorithm from STL, or some other Qt file)

At the beginning I thought I pressed step into or had some other breakpoint and it stopped there, but I tried it with only setting one breakpoint

Any ideas?

It was suggested it's a duplicate question ([Setup GDB with QtCreator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305097/setup-gdb-with-qtcreator)) but it's not, because as I said in my case all breakpoints work, the program stops at the correct line, but step over doesn't work, even when I step into and then step out the code doesn't return to the previous line of code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setup GDB with QtCreator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305097/setup-gdb-with-qtcreator)

Comment: it's not a duplicate, maybe the title but not the problem. In my case it stops in all breakpoints correctly, I just cannot step over the line, or if I step into and then step out it doesn't return me to the previous part of the code, most of the times it jumps to some other part of the code

Also I'm in debug with no optimizations

Comment: Is your build debug without optimization?

Comment: yes I've checked it's in debug and there are no optimizations flags.

The only thing I can think of is that I'm developing for Linux inside a VM (specifically VirtualBox) from a Win10 machine. I've asked the company if they can provide me with a native Linux machine but they said the only supported system is Windows, otherwise I would need to create a secondary partition or use a secondary disk and do the installation myself, which I'm not prepared to do

Comment: I've asked my colleagues if they had a similar problem. Some have it and since they couldn't find a permanent solution  they put a lot of breakpoints and run the code from one to another or use the option to move the curret to another line and select from the menu the option "run to line". They have stopped using step into and/or over